# Simplest/Fastest way to input elements in an List/array (Java)?

Tags: java, performance, lambda

The following code using Java8 works well

```
List<String> strings = IntStream
.range(0,scanner.nextInt())
.mapToObj(i -> scanner.next())
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What this does is:

```
for(i=0; i<scanner.nextInt(); i++){
    list.add(sc.next());
}
```

What would be a suitable (similar) way to build a list of input integers? Alternate ways are welcome too!

Comment: Program for readability, not performance. I/O overhead will probably be 100x the time taken for this processing.

Comment: @chrylis, I don't find this code illegible. would you care to explain a little or point me in the right direction about I/O overhead? And also note that I'm trying to familiarize myself with Java8.

Comment: The answer should be pretty obvious. If `next()` returns a string, call a method that returns integer, namely, `nextInt()`. Or add a `.map(Integer::valueOf)`.

Comment: I didn't say it was illegible. I said that in general performance-chasing is not a concern that you should prioritize.

Comment: Oh I came across this form of coding in a discussion forum where I received TLE. Plus this form was new for me, so thought I'd experiment a little and learn at the same time.
`for(i=0; i<scanner.nextInt(); i++){
    list.add(sc.next());
}`
is this the preferred way?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured this one out.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Created by sbsatter on 3/6/17.
 */
public class Main {
    public static void main(String ... args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list = IntStream.range(0,sc.nextInt()).map(i -> sc.nextInt()).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(list);
    }
}
```

Any better options?

Comment: This doesn't compile. `boxed()` doesn't exist on `Stream` (which is returned by `mapToObj()`).

Comment: This compiled and ran perfectly on my device. Do you have Java8? Have you added proper imports?

Comment: That's not possible. You probably have a copy/paste error.

Comment: I ran this exact code. It's been edited now, please check. Previously, I actually wrote the line. This time however, I ran it first to check!
Please find the docs for boxed:
[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--]

Comment: It'll work now that you changed `mapToObj` to `map`.

Comment: oh, yes, my apologies.

Comment: There are libraries that have primitive list types (apache commons collections & eclipse collections come to mind) that dispense with the need for boxing.  That should speed things up.  Also, depending on how many values you expect, if you pre-allocate your list by passing in a size, that will eliminate the time it takes to grow the internal array as you add things.